# Как вынуть из объекта request переданные json?

Tags: json, node.js, express, request

Мне на сервер (`NodeJS` + `express`) передаётся `json` методом `POST`. Как мне найти в объекте `request` `json`?

Comment: `request.body` наверно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request.body

но у вас должен быть включен парсинг для body:

```
router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!